# Why there is no limit to the number of File Descriptor in epoll, but select does have the limit

Tags: select, epoll

select, poll and epoll can help us to implement high performance server.

Why there is no limit to the number of File Descriptor in poll and epoll, but select does have the limit ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What limit are you referring to? Can you link to (and quote from) documentation that specifies the limit you're talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select has an artificial limit hard coded in the library to FD_SETSIZE, which is often 1024.  http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html covers the c10k problem and goes over each method (select, poll, epoll, iocp, etc)

Comment: Linux limits the number of FD that process can create and use. It won't affect the number of FD that epoll can handle **??**

Comment: Oh, it will.  But there are ways to raise the number of FD that linux will allow.  http://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/increase-ulimit-and-file-descriptors-limit/  But Select will always have that hardcoded variable set to, traditionally, 1024.  So if you raised the limit to say, 10,000, Select will still limit you to 1024.

Comment: Note: you can increase select's cap, at least in linux, by changing the size and recompiling the kernel. Other *nix can be harder.  Some IRC server software has instructions on how to recompile linux with a larger number to handle more clients.